# rbenv crashing when installing ruby binaries

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I updated this Lenovo laptop to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, installed Ruby (3.1.2), rbenv (1.1.2), then Rails (7.0.3) without issue. However, rbenv consistently crashes when I try to install new ruby executables. Thus far I've tried 2.7.2 (compatible with an old Jekyll blog) and 3.0.2. GCC 11.2.0 is being used for compilation. I've reviewed the ruby-build log but don't yet understand how to proceed.

2.7.2 compilation output shown below. Ideas?

````
BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 using ruby-build 20220426-3-g1038c07)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20220526150603.174696.lPGT5x
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20220526150603.174696.log

Last 10 log lines:
ripper.y: At top level:
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
linking shared-object ripper.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20220526150603.174696.lPGT5x/ruby-2.7.2/ext/ripper'
linking shared-object date_core.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20220526150603.174696.lPGT5x/ruby-2.7.2/ext/date'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20220526150603.174696.lPGT5x/ruby-2.7.2'
make: *** [uncommon.mk:295: build-ext] Error 2```
````

Comment: I'm expecting `/tmp/ruby-build.20220526150603.174696.log` to show that we're missing some core dependency. Any useful messages in that file?

Comment: I noticed this near the end of the log file: 
    make[2]: *** [Makefile:313: ossl_pkey_rsa.o] Error 1

Comment: Can you https://pastebin.com/ that file and share the link?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MLR8xgyN

Comment: Older Ruby versions are not compatible with Ubuntu 22.04 unless you build with another version of OpenSSL. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72046299/rbenv-install-fails-after-updating-to-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish

Comment: But I try to install v3.0.0 and that also give error. I could only install 3.1.2

Answer (score 1):

Install the following dependencies ([rbenv/ruby-build wiki](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#suggested-build-environment)), then try building/installing ruby.

```bash
$ apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm6 libgdbm-dev libdb-dev
```

Comment: You may need to build an earlier version of OpenSSL for that particular release of ruby. See: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/1940#discussioncomment-2663209

Comment: This just gets weirder.

- uninstalled ruby, rbenv & ruby-build.

- installed the dependencies mentioned by @richard, above

- reinstalled ruby via apt (3.0.2). Confirmed irb works.

- reinstalled rbenv.

- $rbenv install 3.1.2 (valid, according to $ruby-build -l) - successful.

- $rbenv install 2.7.6 (also valid per ruby-build) - failed.

- moved to a new empty directory; $rbenv local 3.1.2 --> permission denied.

- $sudo rbenv local 3.1.2 --> not installed.

That's it for now. I need a tall cool drink.

Comment: @BrianPiercy Careful with using `sudo` with rbenv. Even a single run with sudo may break your setup, because it's possible rbenv creates files owned by root and now your non-sudo user will not have proper access any more.